# How to save the result of printf to a variable in GDB?

Tags: scripting, debugging, gdb

```
(gdb)printf "Hello %d", 7
Hello 7
(gdb)set $MyVar = printf "Hello %d", 7 // ???
```

How to save the result of `printf "Hello %d", 7` to $MyVar?

Comment: Which result?  The return value, or the string that is printed to stdout?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

eval does a printf of its arguments and then runs it as a command. So you can take your printf argument list, insert `set $MyVar =` at the beginning, and eval it.

```
(gdb) eval "set $MyVar = \"Hello %d\"", 7
(gdb) print $MyVar
$2 = "Hello 7"
```

Comment: cool!  now do it in `crash` ("wrapped" gdb for analyzing Linux kernel crashes)

 http://people.redhat.com/anderson/

Comment: @nhed crash appears to use gdb 7.6, and gdb 7.6 has an `eval` command. When you execute the `eval` statement in this answer, what error do you get?

Comment: Note: I have to prefix `eval` with `gdb` because crash has it's own `eval` which does something different

so `gdb eval "set $MyVar = \"Hello %d\"", 7` works fine, but where I to pass something that takes more than one character to represent i have an issue

```
crash> gdb eval "set $MyVar = \"Hello %d\"", 9
crash> gdb eval "set $MyVar = \"Hello %d\"", 10
Too many array elements
gdb: gdb request failed: eval "set $MyVar = \"Hello %d\"", 10
```

Comment: But this surely is out of scope of original question and I was just being a nudge

Comment: @nhed Maybe the command needs more quotes and backslashes sprinkled on it. If I can track down a kernel image with debug symbols here, I'll try crash. It's about time I learned it, anyway.